# Running a dataflow batch using flexRSGoal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-dataflow

I found [this article](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs) about running a dataflow batch on preemptive machines.

I tried to use this feature using this script:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run $JOB_NAME \
    --gcs-location gs://.../Datastore_to_Datastore_Delete \
    --flexRSGoal=COST_OPTIMIZED \
    --region ...1 \
    --staging-location gs://.../temp \
    --network XXX \
    --subnetwork regions/...1/subnetworks/... \
    --max-workers 1 \
    --parameters \
datastoreReadGqlQuery="$QUERY",\
datastoreReadProjectId=$PROJECTID,\
datastoreDeleteProjectId=$PROJECTID
```

But this is the result:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) unrecognized arguments:
> --flexRSGoal=COST_OPTIMIZED
>
> To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:   gcloud help --
> SEARCH_TERMS

I run the command `gcloud beta dataflow jobs run help` and seems like this option `flexRSGoal` is not there...

```
# gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 319.0.0
alpha 2020.11.13
beta 2020.11.13
bq 2.0.62
core 2020.11.13
gsutil 4.55
kubectl 1.16.13
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs#pipeline_options)? It seems that the correct command should be:

--flexrs_goal=COST_OPTIMIZED

Comment: Yes, I followed. Either your proposal not working. Looks like this parameter is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `--flexrs_goal` flag [1] is not intended for the `gcloud beta dataflow jobs run` command tool, but for java/python command tools. For example the  `python3 -m ...` command as the ones in [2] (Complete lecture of this doc recommended).

So instead of using:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run <job_name> 
    --flexRSGoal=COST_OPTIMIZE ...
```

Run:

```
python3 <my-pipeline-script.py> \
  --flexrs_goal=COST_OPTIMIZED ...
```

If you prefer to use java just switch the `--flexRSGoal` flag to `--flexRSGoal` and follow [3] instead [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs#python

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#run-wordcount-on-the-dataflow-service

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven